# Can a sequence of probability denisity functions (pdf's) converge to a function which isn't a pdf?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence, radon-nikodym

Let $\{\mu_n\}$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures on  $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $d \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, which are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, with densities $\{f_n\}$. Similarly, let $\mu$ be an absolutely continuous probability measure, with density $f$.

A well known fact in probability theory is that convergence in distribution (weak convergence) of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ does not entail that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere. Another well known result (Scheffé's lemma) is that if $f_n$ converges pointwise everywhere to a probability density, then $\mu_n$ converges in total variation to the pertaining probability measure. In particular:
$$
f_n(x)\to f(x), \, a.e. \, on \, \mathcal{X} \implies \sup_{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})}|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|=0
$$
where $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{X}$.

**QUESTION 1**: Is it possible that $f_n$ converges almost everywhere to some nondegenerate function (i.e. nonnull on a set with positive Lebesgue measure) which **is not** a probability density function but still $\mu_n$ weakly converges to some probability measure?

I was starting from a simple example: let's say that $\mathcal{X}=[0,1]$. We might have that $\mu_n$ assigns no mass to the boundary $\{0,1\}$ but converges weakly to a probabity measure $\mu_*$ whose restriction to $(0,1)$ is absolutely continuous, with density $f_*$ (not a probability density) and such that $\mu_*(\{0\})>0$, $\mu_*(\{1\})>0$. Let's firstly assume that $\{f_n\}$ is dominated by an integrable function $g$ and converges to some function $f_{**}$ a.e. on $(0,1)$: in this case, for every Borel $B \subset (0,1)$, we must have that
$$
\mu_n(B)=\int_B f_n(x)dx \to \int_{B} f_{**}(x)dx =\mu_*(B)
$$
But then (by the properties of Radon-Nikodym derivatives) we must have $f_{*}=f_{**}$ almost everywhere and $f_n \to f_*$ almost everywhere.

**QUESTION 2** Removing the assumption of dominance by an integrable function, can $f_n$ converge to $f_{**} \neq f_*$ on a set of non-null Lebeasgue measure?

Comment: I’m guessing something like: uniform measure on [0,1/n] which has a pdf converges to the delta at 0 which does not, and the pdf does converge a.e. to 0

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm aware of this type of examples. I would be interested in cases where the limiting measure has a "less trivial", e.g. having an absolutely continuous restriction on $(0,1)$ and point masses at $0$ and $1$. I re-edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n(x)=\cases{n^2x&if $\ 0\le x\le\frac{1}{2n}$\\
              n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-x\right)&if $\ \frac{1}{2n}\le x\le\frac{1}{n}$\\
     \frac{n}{2(n-2)}&if $\ \frac{1}{n}\le x\le1-\frac{1}{n}$\\
    n^2\left(x-1+\frac{1}{n}\right)&if $\ 1-\frac{1}{n}\le x\le1-\frac{1}{2n}$\\
    n^2\left(1-x\right)&if $\ 1-\frac{1}{2n}\le x\le1$\\
    0&otherwise.}
$$
Then $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f_*(x)\ $ for *all* $\ x\ $, where
$$
f_*(x)=\cases{\frac{1}{2}&if $\ 0<x<1$\\
0&otherwise.}
$$
If $\ \mu_n(B)=\displaystyle\int_B f_n(x)dx\ $, then $\ \mu_n\ $ are probability measures which converge weakly to the probability measure $\ \mu_*\ $ whose distribution function $\ F_{\mu_*}\ $ is given by
$$
F_{\mu_*}(x)=\cases{0&if $\ x<0$\\
                 \frac{2x+1}{4}&for $\ 0\le x<1$\\
                 1&for $\ 1\le x\ $.}
$$
That is, $\ \mu_*\ $ has atoms of weight $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $ at $\ x=0\ $ and $\ x=1\ $, and the remaining half of its weight is uniformly distributed over the interval $\ (0,1)\ $.